# interp1 output not consistent

Tags: matlab, sample, stretch

So I have this function that I modified slightly that takes in a "main" vector and a "base" vector and stretches/compresses the main vector to the dimensions of the base vector.

```
function output = stretch(main, base)
N=length(main)-1;
X=0:N;
XI=0:(length(main)/length(base)):N;

output=interp1(X,main,XI);
end
```

The base vector always has a length of 1620 so that is the goal.  This works most of the time, but for some "main" vector dimensions, the vector of the stretched/compressed vector is 1619 or 1618.  I have no idea how to apply a correction for this - any thoughts?

Comment: Use `linspace(intialValue,finalValue,numberOfElements)` not `intialValue:increment:finalValue`.

Comment: @David Mate, you're a bloody life saver!  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

@David wrote:

> Use `linspace(intialValue,finalValue,numberOfElements)` not `intitialValue:increment:finalValue.`

Comment: ([Answered in a comment and converted to a community wiki.](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251597/question-with-no-answers-but-issue-solved-in-the-comments))